# MariaDB: Periodic copy of data from local database to remote database

Tags: replication, backup, mariadb, mysqldump, mariadb-10.3

**I need to periodically copy the outcome of a view on our local database to another remote database.**

I've tried using mysqldump which works fine when copying data from tables to tables, but i need to copy the data from either a view or a stored procedure.

As an example I've created a sourcedb and a destinationdb. I need to copy data from the view in sourcedb and append the data in a table at the destinationdb.

Is that possible?

**Mysqldump:** 
mysqldump --skip-add-drop-table -uroot -p*** sourcedb sourceview | sed 's/CREATE TABLE/CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS/g' | mysql -P3306 -uroot -p*** destinationdb

**Error:** 
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 41: Table 'destinationdb.table1' doesn't exist

Comment: `select ... into outfile ...`

Comment: The process needs to be automated. I need to pull the data from my database and insert it into the remote database in one go. I'm writing a small C# program to handle  the remote connection and datatransmission , but i need to find a good way to get the content of a view or a stored procedure.

Comment: which database versions?

Comment: MariaDB 10.3.14

Comment: Consider [connect storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-mysql-table-type-accessing-mysqlmariadb-tables/) on the source and treat the created connect engine table as the destination. Also "or a stored procedure" in your question, how do you consider a stored procedure a source?

Answer (score 0):

For much more flexibility, you may consider to use mysqldump **--tab** option.

According to your error,
please make sure that the table is exists in the destination database at remote machine. If it's not, create it first.

Here is some simple steps :

1. Prepare new fresh directory for local files and make sure it accessable by mysqldump

> rm -rf /local-backup;
> mkdir -p /local-backup/today;
> chmod 1777 /local-backup/today /local-backup;
> cd /local-backup

2. Actual mysqldump and get tab separated file

> mysqldump adb atable --tab="today"

3. upload the file generated to remote server. you may use scp or rsync
4. at remote server, execute:

> LOAD DATA CONCURRENT INFILE '/fullpath/of_the_file' IGNORE INTO TABLE adb.atable;